# Creating a multiline label inside a custom togglebuttonbar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

i have a custom toggleButtonBar class that allows label placement on the button, however, i would like to have the labels to be multiline. I'm not good at extending default components. Is there anyone that can help me out?

```
package com.vit2print.plugin.transvit.tools
{
    import mx.controls.Button;
    import mx.controls.ToggleButtonBar;
    import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;

    public class IconToggleButtonBar extends ToggleButtonBar
    {
        [Inspectable(enumeration="left,right,top,bottom", defaultValue="left")]
        public var labelPlacement:String = "left";

        override protected function createNavItem(label:String, icon:Class=null):IFlexDisplayObject {
            var b:Button = Button(super.createNavItem(label, icon));
            b.labelPlacement = labelPlacement;
            return b;
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You've tagged your question `Flex4`, but you extend the `mx` ToggleButtonBar. Which one is it? This will be a lot easier if you can use Spark components.

Comment: edit: Sorry,  i cant use spark components

Comment: Did I just take 15 min. of my time to write you an answer and did you change that comment from 'yes' to 'no' in the meantime, or am I dreaming?

Comment: Sorry, i tried to change it as fast as i could but apparently it was still to late. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you can use Spark components, you can accomplish this through a custom skin for the buttons of the ButtonBar. When skinning the ButtonBar, you'll have to create 4 skins though:

- one for the ButtonBar itself
- one for the first button
- one for the middle buttons
- one for the last button

Unless all the buttons can look the same, in which case you'll need only one skin for all three kinds of buttons.

First create the three (or one) skins for the buttons by copying the default Spark ToggleButtonSkin. In the FlashBuilder wizard that would look like this:

[image]

Scroll down to the bottom and find the Label tag with id `labelDisplay`. It has its `masDisplayedLines` property set to `1`. Remove it or set it to a value that is more convenient for your use case.

Now create a skin for the ButtonBar itself by copying the default Spark ButtonBarSkin. Find the three button factories and replace the `skinClass` styles with the button skin(s) you've just created.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component id="firstButton">
        <s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="net.riastar.skins.MyButtonBarFirstButtonSkin" />
    </fx:Component>

    <fx:Component id="middleButton" >
        <s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="net.riastar.skins.MyButtonBarButtonSkin" />
    </fx:Component>

    <fx:Component id="lastButton" >
        <s:ButtonBarButton skinClass="net.riastar.skins.MyButtonBarLastButtonSkin" />
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>
```

Now apply this skin to your ButtonBar and you're all set.

```
<s:ButtonBar dataProvider="{dp}" skinClass="net.riastar.so.MyButtonBarSkin" width="200" />
```

**Remember**, in general with Spark components: if you want them to *look* different without really changing / customizing their behaviour, use skinning instead of custom components.