# Flex 4: Create transparent skin for ButtonBar

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I'm creating a skin for my ButtonBar component because I need to use toolTips. How do I make it transparent? How do I remove all the drawing except for the label and the toolTip?

Thanks for any helpful tips.

Comment: This answer will show you how to create a skin for the Spark ButtonBar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11185055/creating-a-multiline-label-inside-a-custom-togglebuttonbar/11186646#11186646

Comment: Great article, RIAstar. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create individual skins for the buttons.  There is a skin for first button, middleButtons and last button.  Make them transparent plus any styling you want.  Here is a link to the docs about it:  [Button Bar and Tab Control Skins](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-59bf082612135c9e688-8000.html#WS685c4ccbb85d340c37aa4c55121d51f471a-8000)